# SQL query running slow after including the OR checking inside WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms-2012

This is my query  .After i comment the part OR (NITransactionStatus = 'SUCCESS') ,there is no slowness.
 How can i modify this query such that there is no slow and also i need to include both the conditions thats inside 'WHERE' clause?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM IN_CTD D 
INNER JOIN IN_CTC C 
ON C.InwardCustFileId = D.InwardCustFileId 
WHERE (D.CurrentStatusId = 30) OR (NITransactionStatus = 'SUCCESS')
```

Trying to make it brief :

While i excute this query,it takes too much time to complete its execution . After i comment the 'OR' checking,there is no slowness.The 'IN_CTD' table mentioned in the query contains 2830539 records and the table 'IN_CTC' have 1965 records.How can i modify this query including the 'OR' checking such that it won't take much time to execute ?

Comment: Your query already looks pretty tight.  Do you have any indices setup, and have you tried running `EXPLAIN` to see what SQL Server is doing under the hood?

Comment: Use  with (NOLOCK)  inner join.

Comment: Are there any indexes on the CurrentStatusID and NITransactionStatus columns?  In fact, which table is the NITransactionStatus column on?

Comment: Both the columns have indexes created on them. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: NITransactionStatus  column is used inside the table IN_CTD . @DancingFool

Comment: How much time is this query actually taking, and again, what does `EXPLAIN` tell you?

Comment: 93% of execution cost is used inside the table 'IN_CTD' and also it is mentioned as "NON-clustered_Index seek" on the execution plan. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: You have almost 3 million records in the `IN_CTD` table, and, even with good indices, it will take some time for this query to execute.  Note that SQL Server needs to touch every record, because you are expecting back a count.

Comment: is there any other solution to make it fast with a modification in my query? @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Avoid using OR , you cant try using UNION

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try sub query. If NITransactionStatus column is on IN_CTD table, try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM IN_CTC C 
INNER JOIN (SELECT InwardCustFileId FROM IN_CTD WHERE (CurrentStatusId = 30) OR (NITransactionStatus = 'SUCCESS')) AS D
ON C.InwardCustFileId = D.InwardCustFileId
```

If NITransactionStatus column is on IN_CTC table, try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM IN_CTC C 
INNER JOIN (SELECT InwardCustFileId FROM IN_CTD WHERE CurrentStatusId = 30) AS D
ON C.InwardCustFileId = D.InwardCustFileId 
WHERE (NITransactionStatus = 'SUCCESS')
```

Hope it can help.

Comment: sorry to hear that. hope someone can help you.